# How to set up a junction table in Django

Tags: python, django, django-models

I'm trying to figure out the best way to model this data structure. I want to have a table of "Players" and and table of "Games" such that each game includes two or more players. E.g.

Players

```
PlayerID | PlayerName
1        | John
2        | Sue
3        | Bob
```

Games

```
GameID | GameDate
1      | 1/1/2014
2      | 2/1/2014
```

GamePlayers  (junction table)

```
GamePlayerID | GameID | PlayerID 
1            | 1      | 1
2            | 1      | 2
3            | 1      | 3
4            | 2      | 2
5            | 2      | NULL
```

Notice the NULL value. This basically says "Game 2" consists of player 2 **and one undetermined** player.  This functionality is what I need to replicate in Django.  This is what I tried.

Models.py

```
class Player(models.Model):
    player_name = models.CharField(max_length=60)

class Game(models.Model):
    players = models.ManyToManyField(Player, blank=True)
    game_date = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)
```

But with this setup I can't seem to replicate the functionality I described above. How do I accomplish this?